# Very first hello world java program works in Eclipse but not in command prompt

Tags: java

I know this question has been answered before but as a total newbie trying to start learning Java i'd be grateful please for a specific answer?

In Eclipse when i press run with the following code it works fine

```
public class MySweetProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello there!");

    }


}
```

However when i go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_241\bin in a command prompt and type java MySweetProgram i get an error saying cannot load or find main class MySweetProgram

I've searched through other threads that advise to set the classpath. Mine is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_241\lib.
I changed the folder in Classpath from lib to bin but got the same error, so i changed it back again

I do a java -version and get the following :

java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

Would someone be able to advise me please on what they think may be the issue?
I apologise if this is an ignorant question
Thanks
Jimmy

Comment: This depends on in what "package" the `MySweetProgram` is stored in.  However, you should start at the directory above the root package for the project and use `javac path/to/class/MySweetProgram.java` to make sure it's compiled.  You can then use `java path.to.class.MySweetProgram` to run it

Comment: No, its in my C:\Users\****\eclipse-workspace\Hello\bin folder. But when I run the same command from there I get the same error

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's the first ever class. I'd expect it to be the default package.

Comment: yes it is called 'deafult package' in the SRC folder

Comment: @JimmyJ Change directories to the `src` folder (inside it), then simply use `javac MySweetProgram.java` to compile it and `java MySweetProgram` run it - been a long time since I did any CLI

Comment: @Scratte Ah, good old default package ... that's not going to cause any issues 

Answer (score 1):

welcome! Eclipse will be compiling the code for you and then running it. It does this all for you when you click run, to make your life as a developer slightly easier. If you would like to compile and run the command from the command line, you will need to ensure you have access to the jdk (which must be installed somewhere by Eclipse, but may not be immediately obvious where... a folder called /something/jdk/, presumably). With that on the path (in the %PATH% variable), the following should work for you:

```
cd /to/where/your/code/is
javac MySweetProgram.java
java -cp . MySweetProgram
```

Have a look into compilation and what it means, so you gain a better understanding of what Eclipse is doing. And good luck to you!

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. Running java -cp . MySweetProgram now gives this error: C:\Users\a\eclipse-workspace\Hello\src>java -cp . MySweetProgram
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MySweetProgram has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: You have a more recent version of javac than the version of java that is on your path. There should be a `java.exe` shipped with the jdk you used. Please use this newer version explicitly and try again. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a `.java` file, in your case the `MySweetProgram.java`, you can decide where you want the executable file to go. That file will be called `MySweetProgram.class`. Eclipse may keep those two files in separate directories.

Normally (before Java11) you could only run a `.class` file. So you'd have to add *classpath* (-cp) argument for java to find your file:

```
java -cp path MySweetProgram   (don't put the .class)
```

Now (after Java11) you can run the java file directly because when you give it a `.java` file, it will compile it for you just before executing it:

```
java MySweetProgram.java       (if you're in the directory)
java path\MySweetProgram.java
```

If you have a MySweetProgram.class in the directory, this will give an error.

It gets a little more complicated when you use packages, but Oracle has some very nice [Offical Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)